# ¿Cómo sincronizar los lotes(batches) en petastorm?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Soy nuevo usando petastorm y estoy enfrentando algunos problmas. Necesito recorrer un dataset obteniendo 3 batches(lotes) con los mismos valores para aplicar una transformacion sobre 2 de ellos. El dataset consiste en evaluaciones de usuarios evaluando peliculas (como el dataset de Movie-Lens). Cada fila del dataset posee el id de usuario el id de la pelicula y la evaluación. Necesito obtener 3 lotes con las mismas filas con el fin de extraer los usuarios del lote que emitieron evaluaciones(dado que pueden estar repetidos), las peliculas que fueron evaluadas (dado que pueden estar repetidas) y las evaluaciones( el lote sin transformar).
Para eso escribí el siguiente código.

Crear dataset de prueba y el conversor de spark:

```
ratings_l = [
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 2.18},
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 3.83},
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 3.94},
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 4.31},
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 4.48},
    {'uid_dec': 0, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 3.74},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 3.21},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 2.05},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 2.24},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 2.08},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 4.94},
    {'uid_dec': 1, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 4.22},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 3.52},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 2.67},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 2.69},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 2.75},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 4.93},
    {'uid_dec': 2, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 2.9},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 2.0},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 2.9},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 4.74},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 2.5},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 2.18},
    {'uid_dec': 3, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 4.93},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 4.46},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 2.23},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 4.42},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 4.67},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 2.65},
    {'uid_dec': 4, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 2.11},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 6, 'eval': 2.31},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 7, 'eval': 2.69},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 8, 'eval': 2.41},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 9, 'eval': 4.62},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 10, 'eval': 3.96},
    {'uid_dec': 5, 'mid_dec': 11, 'eval': 2.23}
]

train_ds = spark.createDataFrame(ratings_l)

conv_train = make_spark_converter(train_ds)
```

Obtener tres lotes del mismo objeto conversor( con la esperanza de que los lotes sean iguales):

```
epochs = 4
batch_size = 6
with conv_train.make_tf_dataset(batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=epochs, seed=1) as train, \
     conv_train.make_tf_dataset(batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=epochs, seed=1) as train1, \
     conv_train.make_tf_dataset(batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=epochs, seed=1) as train2:
     epoch_eval = True
     for i, (b, b1, b2) in enumerate(zip(train, train1, train2)):
        if i%(36//batch_size) == 0:
            print('==========Epoch==========: {0}'.format(i//(36//batch_size)))
        print('==========Batch: {}'.format(i%(36//batch_size)))
        print(b[0].numpy())
        print(b1[0].numpy())
        print(b2[0].numpy())
```

Y aquí muestro la salida:

```
==========Epoch==========: 0
==========Batch: 0
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
==========Batch: 1
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
==========Batch: 2
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
==========Batch: 3
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
==========Batch: 4
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
==========Batch: 5
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
==========Epoch==========: 1
==========Batch: 0
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
[2.18 3.83 3.94 4.31 4.48 3.74]
==========Batch: 1
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
[3.21 2.05 2.24 2.08 4.94 4.22]
==========Batch: 2
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
[3.52 2.67 2.69 2.75 4.93 2.9 ]
==========Batch: 3
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
[2.   2.9  4.74 2.5  2.18 4.93]
==========Batch: 4
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
[4.46 2.23 4.42 4.67 2.65 2.11]
==========Batch: 5
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
[2.31 2.69 2.41 4.62 3.96 2.23]
```

Se supone que todos los lotes debieran ser iguales como los que aparecen en el Batch5 del Epoch1 de la salida, pero hay algunos lotes que contienen elementos diferentes como en el Batch2 del Epoch1.

Alguien sabe ¿Por qué esto sucede? O, al menos, ¿Cómo se corrige?
Saludos y gracias de antemano